# C++: How to check which datatype used in a template function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, templates

I need to use different functions for each type, but most of the code remains unchanged.

How do i test which datatype (or structs) i received to my template function parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do i test which datatype (or structs) i received to my template function parameter?

Why should you? If you want to use a template, it's because the code is the same for every type. Otherwise you just use regular overloaded functions.

On the other hand, if you have *just a part of the algorithm* that needs to be type-specific, nothing stops to use an overloaded subfunction called from the template main function:

```
template <typename T>
bool IsFooBar(T Baz)
{
    // here the code is common for every type
    // ...
    // Here Baz must be modified in a type-speficic way:
    DoQuux(Baz);
    // ...
    return /* ... */;
}

// DoQuux is a regular overloaded function
void DoQuux(int & Baz)
{
    // ...
}

void DoQuux(double & Baz)
{
    // ...
}

void DoQuux(std::string & Baz)
{
    // ...
}

// ... other DoQuux ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your template should have a template parameter list:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void f(T t, U u) { }
```

If you call `f(x, y)`, then in the function template `f`, `T` and `U` are the types deduced from the arguments `x` and `y`.  (You can do things much more complex than this, of course, but this is the most basic use case.)

Answer (score 0):

If partial template specialization isn't enough, you could use [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) to compare the type of an object to the type of another. For example, if your template took two type args, you could test `typeid(T) == typeid(U)` to see if they were the same.

Comment: Ah, but its not possible to check to specific type, only the difference of two types can be tested?

Comment: Well, you can also test `typeid(T) == typeid(std::string)` or whatever, but that is a problem best solved at compile-time using template specialization, because RTTI is a bigger performance hit.